# Request for tag merge of gravity & specific-gravity tags

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

Both tags have the same meaning & even similar definitions.  I propose we merge into `specific-gravity` as someone typing `gravity` would still find the former through auto-suggest.

Comment: Sounds good to me...

Comment: Completed......

Answer (score 1):

I agree, can we get a community consensus (comment or vote plz), then I (or one of the other mod's) can merge them.

Comment: I've proposed 'specific-gravity'.  Unless someone comments otherwise, it's got 2 votes already, so let's take it.

Comment: Define getting a consensus?  Should we do it in the Chat?  Maybe we'll get consensus by 2020.

Comment: @brewchez, :-) we should call a meeting and enforce quorum of 60%. j/k. I just wanted a bit of additional feedback. I'll push this through today (unless it's been done already)